# How to open a maven project on emacs with lsp-java?

Tags: java, emacs, maven-3

I have the following .emacs configuration, yet I can not open the project, in emacs.I can open an individual file,  Java and DAP Debug items in the menu, but I don't know how to  compile, run tests, debug and refactor, any help would be appreciated.

```
(package-initialize)

(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)


(use-package lsp-mode
  :init
  (setq lsp-prefer-flymake nil)
  :demand t
  :after jmi-init-platform-paths)

(use-package lsp-ui
  :config
  (setq lsp-ui-doc-enable nil
        lsp-ui-sideline-enable nil
        lsp-ui-flycheck-enable t)
  :after lsp-mode)

(use-package dap-mode
  :config
  (dap-mode t)
  (dap-ui-mode t))

(use-package lsp-java
  :init
  (defun jmi/java-mode-config ()
    (setq-local tab-width 4
                c-basic-offset 4)
    (toggle-truncate-lines 1)
    (setq-local tab-width 4)
    (setq-local c-basic-offset 4)
    (lsp))

  :config
  ;; Enable dap-java
  (require 'dap-java)

  :hook (java-mode   . jmi/java-mode-config)

  :demand t
  :after (lsp lsp-mode dap-mode jmi-init-platform-paths))


(add-to-list 'exec-path "/usr/local/bin")


(set keyboard-coding-system nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile) for running your projects (`s-p u` with e.g. `mvn spring-boot:run`), running tests (`s-p T`) etc. For refactoring, try code actions in lsp-mode (`s-l a a`), organizing inputs (`s-l r o`), etc.